# Workaround for the xfce indicator plugin

Tags: xfce, xfce-panel

The xfce "indicator plugin" keeps crashing with almost all apps. However I need it. I just want it to keep trying to restart itself automatically (preferably every 10 seconds) instead of displaying this annoying message `Plugin "Indicator Plugin" unexpectedly left the panel, do you want to restart it?` Does anyone have an idea about how to do this?

Answer (score 6):

You could always remove the indicator and use the native XFCE notification area... I've found the indicator plugin under XFCE to be a pain to work with.

Comment: okay how do I get this notification area?

Comment: It actually should be running already. If you have a laptop you will need to tell the power manager to always show the icon first. Settings Manager>Power Manager>General (page on left)>System tray icon> set it to "Always show icon" or When battery is present". Once that is done, right click on your XFCE panel>Panel>Panel Preferences>Items (tab)> remove Indicator Plugin. Make sure the "Notification Area" is listed, if not just click "Add new item to this panel" and search for it in the list. That will at least stop the errors about the indicator plugin and retain power and network icons.

Comment: oh I found it. I had it working but it doesn't show my google hangouts plugin for example while the indicator plugin does!

Comment: I'm having this problem as well, but with Skype and WPA GUI. Strangely on another machine with the exact same distro both these icons appear as they should in the "Notifications" panel. Not a big problem, just annoying as the "Indicators" panel doesn't honour my dark theme.

Comment: I eventually found a solution to the Notifications panel issue: a missing 32-bit package (sni-qt:i386) is required for the XFCE "Notifications" panel to work properly with QT apps in 64-bit XFCE. This package was not automatically installed on my machine and installing it fixed my problem: `$ sudo apt-get install sni-qt:i386` Bye-bye "Indicators" panel, you won't be missed :)

Comment: Do not forget to also [**unselect** `Indicator Application`](http://askubuntu.com/a/566270/164341) under `Application Autostart` in `Session and Startup` !!!

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem and found a bug report with a [workaround](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-indicator-plugin/+bug/1311606) that seems to do the trick. The workaround is as follows. I modified it a little so that you don't need to actually right click the active indicator panel, which could be tricky if it keeps crashing.

1. Right click the panel and select `Panel -> Panel Preferences`
2. Select the *Items* tab and add *Indicator Panel* if it's not already there
3. Select *Indicator Panel* and click the edit button (spanner over a page)
4. Click the *Hidden* checkbox next to *Application Menus (Global Menu)*
5. Restart the panel: xfce4-panel -r

The screenshot below shows how what these menus should look like.

[image: Screenshot of preferences to hide panel]

Comment: I do not understand why to follow all these 1-4 steps which goes nowhere because is no restart at the end of the tunnel instead directly step 5? Just wonder the logic, maybe I missed a point.

Answer (score 2):

I spent a few hours on pages like this as I've had a problem with it instantly getting the 'unexpectedly left the panel' error as I try to execute the Indicator Plugin, with no way of accessing the settings.

I had compiled gtk3.12 earlier, which seemed to be the root of the problem. Luckily I hadn't nuked the folder from my trash, and restoring it and running `sudo make uninstall` from the gtk3.12 compile folder fixed it. On the off chance someone did the same or similarly, I might save a few hours of headaches and frustration.